# Ionic 3 local notification LED/Sound not working in Android

Tags: ionic3, localnotification

I have been trying to make an app that has an alarm like feature. I decided to use localnotification as it would play sound and even display notifications .
But it doesn't seem to work.
I have tried all the solutions available on Stack already. But it doesnt play neither Custom sound nor default sound nor displays any LED color, only the notification is shown.

Here is my code :

```
ionViewDidLoad() {

      // Schedule a single notification
this.callnotify();

  }
  callnotify()
  {

  this.localNotifications.schedule({
  id: 1,
  text: 'Single ILocalNotification',
 sound: 'res://platform_default',
  led: 'FF0000'

});
  this.localNotifications.schedule({
   text: 'Delayed ILocalNotification',
   trigger: {at: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 7200)},
   led: 'FF0000',
   sound: 'file://assets/sounds/serious-strike.mp3'
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First try by setting one notification at a time.

```
constructor(public platform: Platform){}

ionViewDidLoad() {
 this.callnotify();
}
callnotify(){
 this.localNotifications.schedule({
    text: 'Delayed ILocalNotification',
    trigger: {at: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 7200)},
    led: 'FF0000',
    vibrate: true,
    sound: this.platform.is('android') ? 'file://assets/sounds/serious-strike.mp3': 'file://assets/sounds/serious-strike.mp3',
 });
}
```

Comment: Tried, the notification comes as  with a delay, vibrates, but no sound or LED.

Comment: Hi, have you solved the issue? I'm facing the same.